# ZFS issues with incremental send: IV set guid missing

Tags: zfs

I've been using ZFS without much troubles so far, but today I got a quite strange error. I was basically doing an incremental send (encrypted hard drive) with something like:

```
$ sudo zfs send -w -v -i  "#myoldsnap" "mylocalzfspool/encrypted_home@mynewsnap" | sudo zfs recv myexternalpool/backup/Laptop -F
send from mylocalzfspool/encrypted_home#myoldsnap to mylocalzfspool/encrypted_home@mynewsnap estimated size is 13.8G
total estimated size is 13.8G
cannot receive incremental stream: IV set guid missing. See errata 4 at https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-ER.
```

**But**, if I replace `#myoldsnap` with `@myoldsnap` (i.e. if I use snapshots instead of bookmarks), then it works... However, I would prefer to use bookmarks since later on I may mant to remove snapshots to save space.

In case it helps, here is the proof that I do have my old snapshot on the external disk, and my bookmark on the local disk:

```
$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot -o name
NAME
mylocalzfspool/encrypted_home@myoldsnap
mylocalzfspool/encrypted_home@mynewsnap
[...]
myexternalpool/backup/Laptop@myoldsnap


$ sudo zfs list -t bookmark 
NAME                                                                                 USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
mylocalzfspool/encrypted_home#myoldsnap                            -      -         -  -
mylocalzfspool/encrypted_home#mynewsnap                                     -      -         -  -
```

Any idea why it failed on bookmark? Usually I don't have much issues, meanwhile I just created another volume on the external pool, and I tried once to open ZFS with an older version that was not supporting encryptions and I just got an error... but it's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I had this problem today and wanted to add my findings.

It turned out that in my case sending the bookmark created a bad stream, this could be checked with `zstreamdump` on the source:

```
zfs send -w -i  "#oldsnap" "tank/home@newsnap" | zstreamdump | grep from_ivset_guid
        from_ivset_guid = 0x0
```

The snapshot, however, would create a proper "IV set guid" value:

```
zfs send -w -i  "@oldsnap" "tank/home@newsnap" | zstreamdump | grep from_ivset_guid
        from_ivset_guid = 0x968b62ce478cf1
```

The source Ubuntu was a bit older than the target so I tried `apt upgrade` and then `zpool upgrade tank`, neither of which improved the situation.

However, deleting and then recreating the bookmark with the system upgraded did resolve my issue.